# Android Studio choose Layout don't work (Material.NoActionBar.Fullscreen)

Tags: android, layout, styles

I choosed the Material.NoActionBar.Fullscreen in Android Studio, and I love this design, but if I start my App it is with actionbar and with a bright background.

My style.xml looks like nothin changed after I choose the Material.NoActionBar.... design.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

How is it possible to use this design?

Note: my API is 28, so this should'nt be the problem

Comment: Please don't use the design tag; it's in the process of being removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry! , change code to this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```